# How do I extract data from certain columns in AppScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to fecth some data from a google spreadsheet in an AppScript standalone file.

I tried with this piece of code, but it is definitely incomplete. It raises this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataRange' of undefined
```

My function:

```
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1n2a5iecKo7seMXcef81V_pxWSRjE4agQ9DSoROtf0').getSheets()[0]
function getColumnId(sheet, namecol) {
          var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
          var col = data[0].findIndex((name) => name === namecol) + 1;
          return col;
        }
```

After extracting the column data, I want to store that data in a normal list:

```
var IDCol=getcolumnId(sheet, 'ID')
var AFCol=getcolumnId(sheet, 'AF')
```

Is that possible in this way? I'd do debugging but I do not know how to proceed first with my function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from a column using the function `getColumnId(sheet, namecol)`.

#### Modification points:

- Your function name is `getColumnId`. But you are trying to call the function with `getcolumnId`. I think that an error occurs.
- `var sheet=DriveApp.getFileById('1n2a5ieOMcKo7seMXcef81V_pxWSRjE4agQ9DSoROtf0').getBlob()` is Blob. In your script, an error occurs at `var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()`.
- In order to retrieve the values from the column, I think that it is required to retrieve the values using the value of `col`. For this

#### Modified script:

```js
function getColumnId(sheet, namecol) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var col = data[0].findIndex((name) => name === namecol);
  var transpose = data[0].map((_, c) => data.map(r => r[c])); // Here, "data" is transposed.
  return transpose[col];
}

// Please run this function.
function sample() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the sheet name.
  var IDCol = getColumnId(sheet, 'ID')
  var AFCol = getColumnId(sheet, 'AF')
  console.log(IDCol)
  console.log(AFCol)
}
```

When this modified script is run, the values of columns with the header values of `ID` and `AF`.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

From your following replying and your updated question,

> Hi Tanaike, I will definitely use your approach mapping the values as you said. But first of all I need to read the data from gsheet properly. Please see my Edit and the error is raised. My code is not place in the google spreadsheet itself but in a StandAlone file in AppsScript

> I tried with this piece of code, but it is definitely incomplete. It raises this error:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataRange' of undefined`

If you are trying to directly execute the function `getColumnId(sheet, namecol)` by the script editor, such an error occurs, because `sheet` is undefined. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. From this situation, I thought that you might want to use `sheet`, `IDCol` and `AFCol` as the global variable. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###').getSheets()[0];

function getColumnId(sheet, namecol) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var col = data[0].findIndex((name) => name === namecol);
  var transpose = data[0].map((_, c) => data.map(r => r[c]));
  return transpose[col];
}

var IDCol = getColumnId(sheet, 'ID')
var AFCol = getColumnId(sheet, 'AF')

// Please run this function.
function myFunction() {
  console.log(IDCol)
  console.log(AFCol)
}
```

- In this function, when `myFunction` is run, you can see the values at the log.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I will definitely use your approach mapping the values as you said. But first of all I need to read the data from gsheet properly. Please see my Edit and the error is raised. My code is not place in the google spreadsheet itself but in a StandAlone file in AppsScript

Comment: @alb Thank you for replying. Now I saw your changed question. When I saw it, I cannot understand the method for executing `var IDCol=getcolumnId(sheet, 'ID')` and `var AFCol=getcolumnId(sheet, 'AF')`. For example, if you are trying to directly execute the function `getColumnId(sheet, namecol)` by the script editor, such an error occurs, because `sheet` is undefined. I thought that this is the reason for your issue. So in this case, please include `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp..` in the function.

Comment: @alb By guessing your goal, I added one more sample script Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize again.